# How to link whole (table) button, instead of word only?

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, inline

I'm using an email template with inline style. Unfortunately the button in this template is not linked, but only the word in the button.

My problem: I've linked the whole table, but then it didn't look correctly in Firefox (blue underline, some wrong pixels on left-hand side).

How can I link the whole button correctly?

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="260" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="2a99d8" style="border-radius: 5px;" class="main_color">

                            <tr><td height="13" style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 13px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>
                                    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius: 5px; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; font-family:'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;">
                                                <!-- ======= main section button ======= -->

                                                <div style="line-height: 24px;">
                                                    <a href="" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">FIND OUT MORE</a> 
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="20" align="right">
                                                <img align="bottom" width="6" height="10" style="width: 6px; height: 10px;" src="http://promailthemes.com/raula/img/btn-arrow.png" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr><td height="13" style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 13px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the table in a containing div and use javascript to link to hyperlink the div.

Comment: thanks, that solved it.
   <div onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>